# Establishing a network video stream between two RPi

Tags: networking, video, streaming-video, streaming, vlc

I have two Raspberry Pi connected to the same WiFi network and am trying to get a video livestream set up coming from RPi1's camera and being displayed on RPi2's HDMI screen.

Currently I am setting up the stream with the following code:

```
import socket 
import time 
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
       camera.rosultion = (640, 480)
       camera.framerate = 24

       server_socket = socket.socket()
       server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
       server_socket.listen(0)

       connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('wb')
       try:
               camera.start_recording(connection, format='h264')
               camera.wait_recording(60)
               camera.stop_recording()
       finally:
               connection.close()
               server_socket.close()
```

The client Rpi then attempts to open the stream via VLC player with:

```
vlc tcp/h264://IPADRESS:8000/
```

However this will only, after some loading time, display a single image and then hang immediately. Is there a better way to do a local network stream?
Opening the stream on my PC with the same command works perfectly fine, although it does have 2 to 3 second latency.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Try use raspivid & gstreamer directly? http://archpi.dabase.com/#sending-and-receiving-pi-camera-video-over-the-network